# How to modify XML file with wix toolset

Tags: wix

I have XML file that include a next content:

```
    <!--<appcache appCacheType="None" />-->
<appcache appCacheType="SingleClient" defaultExpiration="3600"/>
```

On installation patch i need to change this content in XML file to:

```
    <appcache appCacheType="None" />
    <!--<appcache appCacheType="SingleClient" defaultExpiration="3600"/>-->
```

What is a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I tried (in vain) to use the [MSI Community Extensions](https://github.com/dblock/msiext) for this purpose, but wasn't able to get them up and running.
I ended up using the `util:XmlFile`-tag from the Util-extension that works flawlessly.

- Add the namespace of the Util-extension to your source-file in the `Wix`-element:

  ```
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
  ```
- Then use it as sub-element of a related component. In your case you want to delete an attribute and change the value of another one. The following should do the trick, just adjust the XPath in the `ElementPath`-attribute to the one that matches your tag (in the example it updates the `appcache`-tag which has an attribute `appCacheType` with the value `SingleClient`) and the filekey of the XML-file:

```xml
<Component Id="myComponentToUpdateTheXmlFile" ... >
    <!-- Removing the defaultExpiration-attribute first -->
    <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateAppCacheTag" Action="deleteValue" ElementPath="//appcache[\[]@appCacheType='SingleClient'[\]]/@defaultExpiration" File="[#MyConfigFile.xml]" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Sequence="1" Name="defaultExpiration" />
    <!-- Now updating the value -->
    <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateAppCacheTag" Action="setValue" ElementPath="//appcache[\[]@appCacheType='SingleClient'[\]]/@appCacheType" File="[#MyConfigFile.xml]" SelectionLanguage="XPath" Sequence="2" Value="None" />
</Component>
```

- Be sure to add the Util-extension also on the commandline when invoking candle and light:

  ```
    <candle or light command line> ... <parameters> ... -ext <PathToWiXExtensions>\WixUtilExtension.dll
  ```

If you want to do this only during e.g. patching, then add the appropriate condition for this component.

Comment: Can't vote for this because your 2nd point is so nebulous.  I think you were going to give a concrete code sample, since you end your sentence with a colon, but it's not there!

Comment: Somehow the code-example was swallowed and not displayed, although being there. Added the `language`-tag for the block-comment and it showed up again. Thanks for pointing me to it.